# Deploying multi container group to Azure Serverless

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, serverless

I have a containerised `Django Rest Framework` application along with a `Celery` container for background task processing and `Redis` container as a broker.

I want to deploy this application to the `Azure Serverless`. I have been trying to look for the solutions but had no luck so far.

Here are the two question I have -

1. Is it possible to deploy multi-container group application to `Azure Serverless`?
2. Is it possible to deploy the tech stack I have stated above to `Azure Serverless`? (please provide an example or a link to the documentation to guide me.)

Project's Docker Configurations -

`docker-compose`

```
version: "3"

services:

  redis:
    container_name: redis-container
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
    restart: always
    command: "redis-server"

  snowflake-optimizer:
    container_name: snowflake-optimizer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/snowflake-backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
        - "80"
    restart: always
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80"
    links: 
      - redis

    
  celery:
    container_name: celery-container
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.celery
    command: "celery  -A snowflake_optimizer worker -l INFO"
    volumes:
      - .:/snowflake-optimizer
    restart: always
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on: 
      - snowflake-optimizer
```

`Dockerfile` (Django Rest Framework)

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc  -y &&\
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev &&\
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    mkdir /snowflake-backend

WORKDIR /snowflake-backend

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY . /snowflake-backend

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -U "celery[redis]"

RUN python manage.py makemigrations &&\
    python manage.py migrate
    
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:80"]
```

`Docker.celery` (Celery)

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev gcc  -y &&\
    apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev &&\
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
    mkdir /snowflake-backend

WORKDIR /snowflake-backend

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

COPY . /snowflake-backend

EXPOSE 80


RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -U "celery[redis]"

CMD [ "celery", "-A", "snowflake_optimizer", "worker", "-l ", "INFO"]
```

Comment: You mean Azure Container Instances?

Answer (score 1):

The questions is what do we mean here by `Azure Serverless`. Usually people associate serverless with serverless functions. As of 2020 November, `Azure Functions` do not support Docker deployment, at least not in a way to be able to deploy a Django application.

Understandably there are other options to be able to deploy containers into Azure:

1. [Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose): they do support multi-container deployments. The container orchestration is limited and you get billed by second.
2. [Azure WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app): it has a preview feature for support for multi-container deployments. Since it is in preview, the pricing may change and there is not much information about orchestration. I think this will be the recommended approach for the deployment described in your question, I would give this a try.
3. [AKS - Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes): this should be used for serious production workloads, obviously it requires Kubernetes knowledge which may be a huge overhead for a momentary simple deployment.

Answer (score 0):

To deploy a multi-container app on Azure Containers Instances using a Docker Compose file using the Azure CLI:

```
az container create --resource-group myResourceGroup --file docker-compose.yaml
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-yaml)

You can also use the docker-compose CLI directly.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose)